# The E-L equations in a non-inertial frame

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

These are from pages 126 and pages 127 about the subject, (EDITED: from L&L A course of theoretical physics) but I don't really get one thing.

> "Thus an accelerated translational motion of a frame of reference is equivalent, regards to its effect on the motion of a particle, to the application of an uniform field of force equal to the mass of the particle multiplied by the acceleration $W$, in the direction opposite to this acceleration.

It seems to me that for his statement to make sense,

$$\partial U/\partial \vec{r}$$
should be equal to $$\partial U/\partial \vec{r}'.$$
I think it is equal, based on a few exersizes I checked regarding atwood machines and half-atwood machines, but it seems to me that the two should not be equal, since $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r}'$ are distinct vectors. And even if they had the same direction regarding acceleration, I am still not convinced as I think $$\partial /\partial x$$ is distinct from $$\partial/\partial (cx)$$ where $c$ is a constant, is provable via the chain rule.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Book%3A_Graduate_Classical_Mechanics_(Fowler)/29%3A_Non-Inertial_Frame_and_Coriolis_Effect/29.01%3A_The_Lagrangian_in_Accelerating_and_Rotating_Frames

Comment: Here's a link. Book 1, of Landau-Lifshitz, although the link will do you justice as it contains basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They really are the same. I will do things in 1d for simplicity. If $x$ and $x'$ are the position coordinates of the inertial and non inertial frames respectively, the origins coincided at $t=0$ and the relative velocity at $t=0$ was $v$, then $x$ and $x'$ are related by
$$x' = x + vt + \frac{1}{2}at^2$$
Now when finding the force, you differentiate the potential with respect to the space coordinate *holding $t$ fixed*, and so
$$ - \frac{\partial U}{ \partial x} = - \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial U}{\partial x'} =  - \frac{\partial U}{\partial x'}$$

Comment: Aha! Thanks a lot for the reply. The trick was that t was fixed; I seem to get it now.